# Extract data with infinite scrolling Ajax with Scrapy

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy, infinite-scroll

I am a beginner in python and scrapy.
I need help, I need to extract a product listing but he site hast a "view more" products at the end that execute with ajax an text/html request and load another html with new products.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class ProdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "easy"
allowed_domains = ["easy.com.ar"]
start_urls = ["https://www.easy.com.ar/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/es/easyar/search/AjaxCatalogSearchResultContentView?searchTermScope=&searchType=1002&filterTerm=&orderBy=&maxPrice=&showResultsPage=true&langId=-5&sType=SimpleSearch&metaData=&pageSize=12&manufacturer=&resultCatEntryType=&catalogId=10051&pageView=image&searchTerm=&minPrice=&categoryId=39652&storeId=10151&beginIndex=12"]
beginIndex_index = 12

def parse(self, response):
    SECTION_SELECTOR = '.thumb-product'
    for soar in response.css(SECTION_SELECTOR):

             Link = 'div.dojoDndItem a ::attr(href)'
             # Marca = 'p.brand a ::text'
             Nombre = 'div.thumb-name a ::text'
             # Link = 'p.brand a ::attr(href)'
             # SKU = './/p[@class="sku"]/text()' #p.sku ::text'
             Price = './/span[@id="tarj-mas-edit"]/text()' #["0"].parentElement.innerText    .//span[@class="thumb-price-e"]/text()

             yield {
               'Link': soar.css(Link).extract_first(),
            # 'Marca': soar.css(Marca).extract_first(),
               'Nombre': soar.css(Nombre).re_first(r'\n\s*(.*)'), # Limpia espacios y caracteres especiales
            # 'Link': soar.css(Link).extract_first(),   
            # 'SKU': soar.xpath(SKU).re_first(r'SKU:\s*(.*)'),
               'Price': soar.xpath(Price).re_first(r'\n\s*(.*)'),
              }
    # here if no products are available , simply return, means exiting from
    # parse and ultimately stops the spider


    self.beginIndex_index += 12
    if beginIndex_index:
        yield Request(url="https://www.easy.com.ar/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/es/easyar/search/AjaxCatalogSearchResultContentView?searchTermScope=&searchType=1002&filterTerm=&orderBy=&maxPrice=&showResultsPage=true&langId=-5&sType=SimpleSearch&metaData=&pageSize=12&manufacturer=&resultCatEntryType=&catalogId=10051&pageView=image&searchTerm=&minPrice=&categoryId=39652&storeId=10151&beginIndex=%s" % (self.beginIndex_index + 12),
                      callback=self.parse)
```

I tried with code above but only 12 products are getting captured. The only parameter that changes in url is "beginIndex=12", Y want to sum +12 to the url until the products listings over. I'm getting stuck with this issue!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use **selenium**, so you can 'click' on the **view more** button and load more data inside your spider.
Here is a sample of spider (I did not test it, but it's the general idea):

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary


class ProdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "easy"
    allowed_domains = ["easy.com.ar"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.easy.com.ar/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/es/easyar/search/aditivos-y-lubricantes"]

    def __init__(self):
        super(ProdSpider, self).__init__()
        binary = FirefoxBinary('C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe')
        self.wb = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

    def parse(self, response):
        self.wb.get(response.url)
        while True:
            view_more_button = self.wb.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Search_Result_div"]/div[2]/div[9]/input')
            if not view_more_button:
                break
            view_more_button.click()
            #extract your data here...
```

Answer (score 1):

You got it !

I see in your URL that you have an other parameter named `pageSize`. I tested it and the website allows you to set it to 50 max.

To know when to stop, you can just test if you have items in `response.css(SECTION_SELECTOR)` before yielding another request :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy import Selector


class ProdSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = "easy"
  allowed_domains = ["easy.com.ar"]

  url = "https://www.easy.com.ar/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/es/easyar/search/AjaxCatalogSearchResultContentView?searchTermScope=&searchType=1002&filterTerm=&orderBy=&maxPrice=&showResultsPage=true&langId=-5&sType=SimpleSearch&metaData=&pageSize=50&manufacturer=&resultCatEntryType=&catalogId=10051&pageView=image&searchTerm=&minPrice=&categoryId=39652&storeId=10151&beginIndex={pagenum}"

  product_fields_xpath = {
    'Link': '//a[contains(@id, "CatalogEntry")]/@href',
    'Nombre': '//a[contains(@id, "CatalogEntry")]/text()',
    'Price': './/span[@class="thumb-price-e"]/text()'
  }

  section_selector = '//div[@class="thumb-product"]'

  begin_index = 0

  def start_request(self):
    yield Request(url=url.format(pagenum=self.begin_index), method='GET', callback=self.parse)

  def parse(self, response):
    products = response.xpath(self.section_selector).extract()
    n_items = 0
    for product in products:
      n_items += 1
      sel = Selector(text=product)
      item = dict()
      for k, v in self.product_fields_xpath.iteritems():
        item[k] = sel.xpath(v).extract_first()
      yield item

    self.begin_index += 50

    if n_items > 0:
      yield Request(url=url.format(pagenum=self.begin_index), method='GET', callback=self.parse)
```

I didn't test this code, but I hope you'll understand what I mean.

Comment: Hi @Benjamin. Thanks for your help! I test this code but didn't work! the minimum products are 12, next ajax html load changes to 24, etc.

Comment: I think it does'nt work because of the mix between `css` extract and `xpath`.
About the minimum, I set the number of products per page to 50. After, I add 50 to the `beginIndex` parameter.
Normally, you'll have by page : 0 -> 49, 50 -> 99, 100 -> 149 etc... And on each page you will not have the same products

Comment: To help you, I modified the above code. I prefer to use xpath (just personnal feeling) and I use Selector to extract data from html string.

Comment: Thanks so much @Benjamin, try this code but didn`t work again! I´ll keep trying to find a solution!